# How to open folder after searching in Apple Script

Tags: applescript

the title is a little confusing but here's what I want to happen:

1. Open finder to folder "Grove"
2. Search command pops up (command f)
3. Searches "Grove" for all files containing the search
4. If only 1 file then that file will be opened

Please help

I'm a bit new to Apple Script so I'm learning as I go. So far I have the Apple Script opening a the finder and then opening the folder "Grove"

This what I currently have

```
tell application "Finder" to open folder "Grove"
end
display dialog "Enter Project Number" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Search"} default button 2
set {text returned:t, button returned:b} to result
if b is "Search" then
    set d to quoted form of (POSIX path of ((path to home folder as Unicode text) & "Grove:"))
end if
set found to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & d & space & quoted form of t)
open result
end
```

Comment: Do you really need to use a Finder search, and is your script actually using one?  Note that the search result is a Finder construct that fakes like it is a Finder window, but it really isn't one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. I just want this folder to be opened and be able to search inside the folder and it'll open up the file I searched for.

Comment: The Finder's search result is not a regular Finder window, so there isn't a handy way to get the items.  You would probably have better luck creating your own Spotlight search query and using that in a `mdfind` shell script - what are the search terms?

Comment: Search terms would be "OV_345" (the 3 digits are an example)and we're trying to recall the folder that's in another larger folder that holds everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
set grover to quoted form of POSIX path of ((path to home folder as text) & "grove:")
--> "'/Users/username/grove/'"

display dialog "Enter Project Number" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Search"} default button 2
set {text returned:t, button returned:b} to result

if b is "Search" then
    set found to (do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & grover & space & quoted form of ("OV_" & t))
    -- shell command will look like this: 
    -- "mdfind -onlyin '/Users/username/grove/' 'OV_345'"
    -- assuming single hit, result should look like this:
    --> "/Users/username/grove/strategy and tactics.txt"
    
    if (count of paragraphs of found) is 1 then
        set foundOne to POSIX file found as «class furl»
        tell application "Finder" to open foundOne
    else
        display alert "More than one result"
    end if
end if
```

I put the entire search bit inside the if…then block since I'm assuming that if the user cancels then everything should stop.

I fed the `open` command to the Finder since otherwise, it will be the Script Editor that tries to open the resulting file (depending on how you run the script). The Finder should know which app owns the file to open based upon its extension.